# Regex - Splitting Strings at full-stops unless it's part of an honorific

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I have a list containing all possible titles:

```
['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Ms.', 'Dr.', 'Prof.', 'Rev.', 'Capt.', 'Lt.-Col.', 'Col.', 'Lt.-Cmdr.', 'The Hon.', 'Cmdr.', 'Flt. Lt.', 'Brgdr.', 'Wng. Cmdr.', 'Group Capt.' ,'Rt.', 'Maj.-Gen.', 'Rear Admrl.', 'Esq.', 'Mx', 'Adv', 'Jr.']
```

I need a Python 2.7 code that can replace all full-stops `\.` with newline `\n` unless it's one of the above titles.

Splitting it into a list of strings would be fine as well.

#### Sample Input:

`Modi is waiting in line to Thank Dr. Manmohan Singh for preparing a road map for introduction of GST in India. The bill is set to pass.`

#### Sample Output:

`Modi is waiting in line to Thank Dr. Manmohan Singh for preparing a road map for introduction of GST in India.
The bill is set to pass.`

Comment: You will have to show some efforts you tried on your own. While you are at it also provide some example output.

Comment: Also an expected input and output would make understanding what you're trying to do a lot easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, here we use a *list comprehension* with a *conditional statement* to concatenate the words with a `\n` if they contain a full-stop, and are not in the list of key words. Otherwise just concatenate a space.

Finally the words in the sentence are joined using `join()`, and we use `rstrip()` to eliminate any newline remaining at the end of the string.

```
l = set(['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Ms.', 'Dr.', 'Prof.', 'Rev.', 'Capt.', 'Lt.-Col.', 
'Col.', 'Lt.-Cmdr.', 'The Hon.', 'Cmdr.', 'Flt. Lt.', 'Brgdr.', 'Wng. Cmdr.', 
'Group Capt.' ,'Rt.', 'Maj.-Gen.', 'Rear Admrl.', 'Esq.', 'Mx', 'Adv', 'Jr.'] )
s = 'Modi is waiting in line to Thank Dr. Manmohan Singh for preparing a road 
map for introduction of GST in India. The bill is set to pass.'

def split_at_period(input_str, keywords):
     final = []
     split_l = input_str.split(' ')

    for word in split_l:
        if '.' in word and word not in keywords:
            final.append(word + '\n')
            continue
        final.append(word + ' ')

    return ''.join(final).rstrip()

print split_at_period(s, l)
```

or a **one** liner :D

`print ''.join([w + '\n' if '.' in w and w not in l else w + ' ' for w in s.split(' ')]).rstrip()`

**Sample output:**

```
Modi is waiting in line to Thank Dr. Manmohan Singh for preparing a road map for introduction of GST in India.
The bill is set to pass.
```

**How it works?**

Firstly we split up our string with a space `' '` delimiter using the `split()` string function, thus returning the following `list`:

```
>>> ['Modi', 'is', 'waiting', 'in', 'line', 'to', 'Thank', 'Dr.', 
'Manmohan', 'Singh', 'for', 'preparing', 'a', 'road', 'map', 'for', 
'introduction', 'of', 'GST', 'in', 'India.', 'The', 'bill', 'is', 
'set', 'to', 'pass.']
```

We then start to build up a new list by iterating through the split-up list. If we see a `word` that contains a period, but **is not** a keyword, (*Ex:* `India.` *and* `pass.` *in this case*) then we have to concatenate a **newline** `\n` to the word to *begin* the new sentence. We can then `append()` to our `final` list, and `continue` out of the current iteration.

If the word does not end off a sentence with a period, we can just concatenate a space to rebuild the original string.

This is what `final` looks like before it is built as a string using `join()`.

```
>>> ['Modi ', 'is ', 'waiting ', 'in ', 'line ', 'to ', 'Thank ', 'Dr. 
', 'Manmohan ', 'Singh ', 'for ', 'preparing ', 'a ', 'road ', 'map ', 
'for ', 'introduction ', 'of ', 'GST ', 'in ', 'India.\n', 'The ', 'bill ', 
'is ', 'set ', 'to ', 'pass.\n']
```

Excellent, we have **spaces**, and **newlines** where they need to be! Now, we can rebuild the string. Notice *however*, that the the last element in the list also happens to contain a `\n`, we can clean that up with calling `rstrip()` on our new string.

---

The initial solution did not support spaces in the **keywords**, I've included a new more robust solution below:

```
import re

def format_string(input_string, keywords):
    regexes = '|'.join(keywords)  # Combine all keywords into a regex.
    split_list = re.split(regexes, input_string)  # Split on keys.
    removed = re.findall(regexes, input_string)  # Find removed keys.
    newly_joined = split_list + removed  # Interleave removed and split.
    newly_joined[::2] = split_list
    newly_joined[1::2] = removed
    space_regex = '\.\s*'

    for index, section in enumerate(newly_joined):
        if '.' in section and section not in removed:
            newly_joined[index] = re.sub(space_regex, '.\n', section)
    return ''.join(newly_joined).strip()
```

Comment: That's a monster of a one-liner! Something clearer might be good!

Comment: @Zaz, I agree aha, updated it.

Comment: nice because no regex involved. pure python: +1 (but I have a hard time understanding how it works :))

Comment: Added an explanation for you @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: Not working with that: `s = 'Modi is waiting in line Maj.-Gen. to Thank Rear Admrl. Manmohan Singh for preparing a road map for introduction of GST in India. The bill is set to pass.'
`: Rear Admrl has dot converted to "\n" because you split words by spaces.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah, good catch! Working on it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, updated it.

Answer (score 0):

- convert all titles (and sole dot) into a regular expression
- use a replacement callback

code:

```
import re

l = "|".join(map(re.escape,['.','Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Ms.', 'Dr.', 'Prof.', 'Rev.', 'Capt.', 'Lt.-Col.', 'Col.', 'Lt.-Cmdr.', 'The Hon.', 'Cmdr.', 'Flt. Lt.', 'Brgdr.', 'Wng. Cmdr.', 'Group Capt.' ,'Rt.', 'Maj.-Gen.', 'Rear Admrl.', 'Esq.', 'Mx', 'Adv', 'Jr.']))

e="Dear Mr. Foo, I would like to thank you. Because Lt.-Col. Collins told me blah blah. Bye."

def do_repl(m):
    s = m.group(1)
    if s==".":
        rval=".\n"
    else:
        rval = s
    return rval

z = re.sub("("+l+")",do_repl,e)
# bonus: leading blanks should be stripped even that's not the question
z= re.sub(r"\s*\n\s*","\n",z,re.DOTALL)
print(z)
```

output:

```
Dear Mr. Foo, I would like to thank you.
Because Lt.-Col. Collins told me blah blah.
Bye.
```

Comment: you are right, that does not cut it. I'll rework the answer

Comment: This replaces the periods, OP wants them in his output?

Comment: OP quote; "I  need a Python 2.7 code that can replace all full-stops \. with newline \n"

Comment: Correct, but his updated output says differently?

Comment: right!! updating answer.